# How to create udev event that runs a command for mx510 usb mouse?

Tags: mouse, udev

I have Logitech mx510 mouse which uses 400cpi resolution by default. I want to set it to 800cpi automatically. How can i set a udev rule that runs `lomoco -8` when I plug in the mouse?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to write a working udev rule.

```
# udev.rules file for Logitech mouse control using lomoco
#

ACTION != "add", GOTO="lomoco_end"
SUBSYSTEM == "usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", GOTO="lomoco_start"
SUBSYSTEM != "usb_device", GOTO="lomoco_end"

LABEL="lomoco_start"

# "M-BS81A",  "MX510 Optical Mouse"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c01d", RUN+="/usr/bin/lomoco -8"

LABEL="lomoco_end"
```